# Como usar o each do thymeleaf?

Tags: html

Observem bem o código no meu controller;

```
@RequestMapping("/produtos/form")
    public ModelAndView form() {

        ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView("produtos/form");
        modelAndView.addObject("tipos", TipoPreco.values());

        return modelAndView;

    }
```

essa é minha pagina html, e escrevir a seguinte anotação no topo da pagina

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
```

com a anotação há cima é possível pega a lista da seguinte forma;

```
<c:forEach items="${tipos}" var="tipoPreco" varStatus="status">
            <div>
                <label>${tipoPreco}</label>
                <input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].valor">
                <input type="hidden" name="precos[${status.index}].tipoPreco" value="${tipoPreco}">
            </div>
</c:forEach>
```

Não existe nada de errado em tudo que foi descrito agora, eu somente queria saber como ficaria no thymeleaf, a única coisa que mudaria seria a parte de html, somente preciso modificar a parte de html.

=======================================================================

Essa foi minha tentativa

```
<select>
    <table>
        <tr th:each="tipo : ${status}">
            <td></input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].valor"></td>
            <td></input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].tipo"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</select>
```

sendo que está gerando esse erro

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

Tue Apr 05 06:43:15 BRT 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Exception parsing document: template="produtos/form", line 31 - column 8
```

===================================================================

Consoles

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: O tipo de elemento tr" deve ser encerrado pela tag final correspondente "</tr>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

eu tentei desta forma;

```
<select>
            <table>
                <tr th:each="tipo : ${status}">
                    <td><input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].valor"></td>
                    <td><input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].tipo"></td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </select>
```

e deu esse erro;

```
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException: O tipo de elemento input" deve ser encerrado pela tag final correspondente "</input>".
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.createSAXParseException(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.util.ErrorHandlerWrapper.fatalError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLErrorReporter.reportError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLScanner.reportFatalError(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanEndElement(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDriver.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentScannerImpl.next(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source) ~[na:1.8.0_65]
```

Comment: Eu fiz minhas tentativas, não precisavam colocar-las como -1

Comment: +1 pelo esforço em fazer a pergunta com muitas informações.

Answer (score 0):

O Problema aparentemente está aqui:

**</input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].valor">**

Altere para :

**<input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].valor">**

---

A tag input não precisa ser fechada.

Comment: Dependendo da forma como se usa o Thymeleaf, ele requer que todas as  tags sejam fechada.

Comment: acabei de atualizar minha postagem, dá uma olhada.

Comment: Então neste caso, feche a tag input, deixando assim: <input type="text" /> e não como estava, </input>

Answer (score 0):

Bom Dia,

Tente assim:

```html
<select>
    <table>
        <tr th:each="tipo : ${status}">
            <td><input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].valor"/></td>
            <td><input type="text" name="precos[${status.index}].tipo"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</select>
```

O thymeleaf é bem rígido com a formatação do HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Primeiro, o nome do seu objeto no Model é "tipos" ou "status"? Se for "tipos", usa o seguinte código:

```html
<table>
  <tr th:each="t,i : ${tipos}">
    <td th:text="${i.index}"></td>
    <td th:text="${t.name()}"></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Informando dois parametros (t,i) no th:each, o Thymeleaf vai retornar o objeto do map e sua respectiva chave (índice).

Como você usa uma classe enum no caso, chamei o método .name() para retornar o nome da sua variável. O método .toString() também pode ser chamado mas daí você teria que sobrescrever ele na sua classe enum.